# Writing to text files in Python 3.4

Tags: text, python-3.x, output

I have simplified my problem.

This code only writes the last text line followed by a CR/LF of the list.txt file into the newlist.txt file.  How come.  It prints all entries one to a line on screen, but only writes the last line to the file.

This is the crux of my first post on this topic, but I am trying to simplify the issue

```
f = open("list.txt","r")
for line in f:
    print(line)
    output = open("newlist.txt",'w', newline="\r\n")
    output.write(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: What language are you using? Looks like Python?

Comment: Sorry yes it's Python

Comment: And what do you actually want to do?

Comment: well I have a much more complex issue but this is the heart of it.  I want to take one file and just write it to another file in this example.  My real script takes a bunch of ping input and writes it to a file.  but it has the same issue.

Comment: Why not using `awk` or something then? Much easier for simple tasks.

Comment: This is just my figuring out how to do much more complex tasks.  awk would sort fine but I will end up using Python to ssh and ftp stuff automatically... this is just my first foray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reopen the file in each iteration. Don't!

That `open()` function (whichever language that is) certainly empties the file before it writes into, considering that `w` flag you hand over. You might want to use an `a` flag instead, most languages use that for "appending" to a file:

```
output = open("newlist.txt",'a', newline="\r\n")
```

But that still means that you reopen the file in every single iteration which is pretty slow. It makes more sense to open the file *once* before the loop. Then you can limit yourself to writing into the already opened file inside the iteration. I don't know python, but probably this is what you are looking for:

```
f = open("list.txt","r")
o = open("newlist.txt",'w', newline="\r\n")
for line in f:
    print(line)
    o.write(line)
o.close()
f.close()
```

@eryksun suggests in his comment below to use the `with` construct of python for a more elegant and robust solution (this is python, right?). I took the liberty to include that suggestion here since it clearly makes sense. I hope I got that right:

```
with open("list.txt") as f, open("newlist.txt", "w", newline="\r\n") as o:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        o.write(line)
```

Looks pretty straight and logical to me, *if* python cleans up as @eryksun states.

Comment: I am new to Python so do not understand your answer.  How do I loop the file.  I understand readlines but I am trying to make the issue as simple as I can to sort it out.

Comment: LOL, one newbie pythoneer trying to help another one. Great.

Comment: HA!  You did it!  Yes yes yes it was just overwriting the file.  Now I can work on my full scale problem!!!! Thank you.  And yes I know it's clumsy but I am a noob at the moment to Python

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for that suggestion! I took the liberty to include that in the answer above, hope that is fine with you?